# Responsive design to align Items in div to the center of the page using HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css

[Output Image I'm getting

```css
.featuress{
  width:70%;
  margin-left:20%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding-bottom:30px;
}
.logo{
    min-width: 60px;
    margin:10px;
    text-align:center;
}
.text{
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #ffa600;
}
body, h2, p {
  margin:0;
}
```

```css
.featuress{
  width:70%;
  margin-left:20%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding-bottom:30px;
}
.logo{
    min-width: 60px;
    margin:10px;
    text-align:center;
}
.text{
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #ffa600;
}
body, h2, p {
  margin:0;
}
```

```html
    <div class="featuress">
    <section id="features">
      <div class="premium">
        <div class="logo1">
      <img class="logo" src="https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/70/70535.png" width="40" alt="premium" />
      </div>
      <div class="text text1">
      <h2>Premium Materials</h2>
      <p>Our trombones use the shiniest brass which is sourced locally. This will increase the longevity of your purchase.</p>
    </div>  
    </div>
      <div class="shipping">
        <div class="logo2">
        <img class="logo" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/09/14/20/39/vans-5572117__480.png" alt="shipping" width="60" />
        </div>
        <div class="text text2">
        <h2>Fast Shipping</h2>
        <p>We make sure you recieve your trombone as soon as we have finished making it. We also provide free returns if you are not satisfied.</p>
      </div>
      </div>
      <div class="quality">
        <div class="logo3">
        <img class="logo loggo3" src="https://i.pinimg.com/736x/0b/a2/d1/0ba2d192c9b874a4df11af1a90a6d1ad.jpg" alt="quality" width="60"/>
        </div>
        <div class="text text3">
        <h2>Quality Assurance</h2>
        <p>For every purchase you make, we will ensure there are no damages or faults and we will check and test the pitch of your instrument.</p>
      </div>
      </div>
    </section>
    </div>
```

][1][Intended Output Style](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r2Ixj.jpg)

```html
<div class="featuress">
  <section id="features">
    <div class="premium">
      <div class="logo1">
        <img class="logo" src="https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/70/70535.png" width="40" alt="premium" />
      </div>
      <div class="text text1">
        <h2>Premium Materials</h2>
        <p>Our trombones use the shiniest brass which is sourced locally. This will increase the longevity of your purchase.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="shipping">
      <div class="logo2">
        <img class="logo" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/09/14/20/39/vans-5572117__480.png" alt="shipping" width="60" />
      </div>
      <div class="text text2">
        <h2>Fast Shipping</h2>
        <p>We make sure you recieve your trombone as soon as we have finished making it. We also provide free returns if you are not satisfied.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="quality">
      <div class="logo3">
        <img class="logo loggo3" src="https://i.pinimg.com/736x/0b/a2/d1/0ba2d192c9b874a4df11af1a90a6d1ad.jpg" alt="quality" width="60" />
      </div>
      <div class="text text3">
        <h2>Quality Assurance</h2>
        <p>For every purchase you make, we will ensure there are no damages or faults and we will check and test the pitch of your instrument.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

**This is the HTML bit of the code I tried writing and the intended format I was looking for is attached along. I just cant quite get it the way its shown. It'd be really helpful if I could be helped with how to align and style just this part of the site using CSS**

Answer (score 1):

You can use `display:flex` and `align-items:center` on your features. I added some style to fit a little bit like your screen.

```css
body, h2, p {
  margin:0;
}
.feature {
  display:flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding-bottom:30px;
}
.logo{
  min-width: 60px;
  margin:10px;
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div class="feature">
  <div class="logo">
    <img src="https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/70/70535.png" width="40"/>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h2>Premium Materials</h2>
    <p>Our trombones use the shiniest brass which is sourced locally. This will increase the longevity of your purchase.</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="feature">
  <div class="logo">
    <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/09/14/20/39/vans-5572117__480.png" width="60" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <h2>Fast Shipping</h2>
    <p>We make sure you recieve your trombone as soon as we have finished making it. We also provide free returns if you are not satisfied.</p>
  </div>
</div>    
<div class="feature">
  <div class="logo">
    <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/736x/0b/a2/d1/0ba2d192c9b874a4df11af1a90a6d1ad.jpg" width="60" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <h2>Quality Assurance</h2>
    <p>For every purchase you make, we will ensure there are no damages or faults and we will check and test the pitch of your instrument.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

**EDIT**

Here is an exemple of what to select with `display:flex`, take a look at [Flexbox (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox).

```css
.container{
  border:1px solid black;
}
.d-flex{
  display:flex;
}
.orange{
  background-color:orange;
}
.green{
  background-color:green;
}
.pink{
  background-color:pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="d-flex container">
  <div class="box-container orange">
    <div class="box">A</div>
    <div class="box">B</div>
    <div class="box">C</div>
  </div>
  <div class="box-container green">
    <div class="box">D</div>
    <div class="box">E</div>
    <div class="box">F</div>
  </div>
  <div class="d-flex box-container pink">
    <div class="box">G</div>
    <div class="box">H</div>
    <div class="box">I</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I did try something similar but my output never comes quite the wqy it sould and I'd add the output I got along with the styling I used; The text after logo always seems to just be beneath the logo and not to the right of it.

Comment: @ALTHAFABDULSALAM I can't tell without more context since it's working in mine. Notice that I moved the `.logo` to it's parent (no longer inside `img`) because I tryed to make a new class `.logo` that was already used. You can keep your old one and change mine to `.logo-container` for example

Comment: Thabk you so much...this did work fine now but may I please ask a small doubt as to why did you use `.feature` class and not the `.featuress` class?.. My error of not getting it right was I was using the super class of `.featuress`. It'd be really helpful if you could kindly tell me the reason behind it. Thank you so much once again :) @Cédric

Comment: @ALTHAFABDULSALAM Indeed I also made a `.feature` class to avoid selecting `.premium`, `.shipping` and `.quality` to do the same thing. By selecting `.features`, you will align the features but not their content. I'm clearing mysnippet to keep used classes

Comment: @ALTHAFABDULSALAM I also added a little snippet to show why I selected `.shipping` `.quality` and `.features` instead of their container.